# How to highlight a person in irssi?

Tags: irssi

I'd like irssi to highlight all messages from a specific nickname. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 5):

From `/help hilight`:

> Hilight all messages from "mynick":
>
> `/HILIGHT -mask mynick!*@*`

Comment: Why did you include the phrase "Please do your research [...] before asking!"?

Comment: That's the instruction in [How to Ask](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask): Do your homework. Have you thoroughly searched for an answer before asking your question?

Comment: Why do you post and answer such a question yourself then (I do not oppose the question just the phrasing)?

Comment: Since I found the answer five minutes after posting the question, I obviously didn't put enough effort into research before asking.